# Round number 0.1 to 0.10

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, double, decimal

I'm doing my C# project to school and I need a help, I have to generate random number from 0.00 to 1.00 to a matrix of size 5*5.

```
double[,] matrix = new double[5, 5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        matrix[i, j] = (rand.Next(0, 100 + 1) / 100.0);
        Console.Write(" {0}", matrix[i, j]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

But when I write those numbers, some number shows like 0.1 and I want to write it like 0.10, how?

Comment: 1. not rounding, 2. use formatted output or a formatted `ToString`

Comment: You know about `Random.NextDouble()` or you want only increments of 1/100 in your matrix?

Answer (score 2):

> But when I write those numbers, some number shows like 0.1 and I want
>   to write it like 0.10, how?

Then you need to make use of `ToString("N2");`

```
Console.Write(" {0}", matrix[i, j].ToString("N2"));
```

Comment: `#` is optional. `0` is mandatory, so I guess you meant `0.00`.

Comment: You can use the format directly in the first parameter, like this: `Console.Write(" {0:N2}", matrix[i, j]);`.

Comment: @TheZerda, you should accept an answer if it solved your problem. On a side note, check out the shorter form in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

To be more explicit for decimals, in case you want to change to more or less precision later...

```
 String.Format("{0:0.00}", matrix[i, j]);
```

Comment: Just changing the number next to the `N` you can get the precision you need. ;) Like in `Console.Write(" {0:N9}", matrix[i, j]);`.

Comment: I was thinking this would give more flexibility for cultures which use , instead of . as hold number separators, but it seems this happens automagically within String.Format for the currently set culture.

I gave an orange arrow to Christos's answer.

Comment: Yes. If you put a comma instead of a point, it will consider it as the thousands separator and therefore use it, not replace the displayed symbol. I think you have to use `string.Format` and the `IFormatProvider` if you want to use a specific culture.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
var d1 = 0.2;
var d2 = 1.20;
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString("0.00"));  // 0.20
Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString("0.00"));  // 1.20
```